# Appcelerator. Handling user sessions

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

Titanium SDK version: 1.6.1
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am a bit confused about what is the best practice when dealing with user "sessions" in Appcelerator apps (iPhone). Like it is now I save the users token in a property and then check on each page that it still exists (like on a webpage). This does not work so good and there must be a better way.

So, what is the best practise for handling user login sessions? Can someone explain the process for me? Step by step.

Thankful for all input!

Comment: Are you looking to expire the user session over a period of time or just verify there authenticated?

Comment: Like it is now I save a property called token with the users token for the API upon login. I want to let the user logout (destroy token) and then re-login as for example another user. So I am looking to verify that the user is stil authenticated (that the token exists). How can I do this in best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been handling authentication verification on iOS as follows:

1. In my app.js on first load I check that the token is valid, if not I display a login.

   I use methods similar to the below

```
    function need2Login(){
      var lastLogin = Ti.App.Properties.getString('last_login');
      if(lastLogin.length==0){
          return true; 
      }

      //add some date validation to expire any tokens

      // return a value based on the validation rules
    };
```

```
function manageLogin(){
    if(need2Login()){
       wLogin.open(); //Open Login window
    }else{
             wMain.open(); //Open Main window
    }   
};
```

1. When the user logs out, I fire an event back to the app.js to reload the login screen
2. I also have the below in my app.js to handle on App Resume I also check if the token is still valid

For the resuming handling I use the following in my app.sj:

1) Check if we're on iOS 4+

```
function isiOS4Plus(){
    // add iphone specific tests
    if (Ti.Platform.name == 'iPhone OS'){
        var version = Ti.Platform.version.split(".");
        var major = parseInt(version[0],10);

    // can only test this support on a 3.2+ device
    if (major >= 4){
        return true;
    }
   }
   return false;
};
```

2) Then add the handler

```
if (isiOS4Plus()){
    // fired when an app resumes for suspension
    Ti.App.addEventListener('resumed',function(e){
       //check if login is still valid
       manageLogin(); //I just reuse my login logic on resume
    });
}
```

Please note this assumes checking the authentication token only needs to be done when the App starts, or resumes.  This should cover most cases, but there are aways ones were it wont fit.

Comment: Looks very interesting. Got a few questions about the code. 1) Why do you check for iOS version? 2) What if a user logs out and never closes the app. How do you check that the user is still logged in? 3) Is it possible that I can se the code used for the event resumed? Thanks!

Comment: You want to check iOS version since below 4 there is no resume. The resume will fire when the user backgrounds there app.  So you should be alright since you'd be check every time they made the App active (from background or fresh start).  The resume/login code is pretty specific to how I handle my sessions.  I'll add alittle but it is really App dependent.

Comment: Ok, things are getting clearer. Like it is now I am replacing the TabBar buttons if the user token does not exist. I do not open a window. Which way is best? Should I open a window instead? Is it possible I could view your code because I am looking for a better way to handle logins (your way).

Comment: Here is alittle more of the code, since it is part of the nav system it is hard to pull all of it out https://gist.github.com/948579   Hopefully this gives you the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I will examine it closely. Hopefully I can use the same system in my app.